# TikZ library is changing the default font

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

NOTE: this question can be deleted. the problem was due to the use of the package times

In my `beamer` `.tex` file I have two frames where I use a `tikzpicture` environment to do some animation. That's why I need to include the TikZ libraries in the premable. But, because of this the fonts in the other frames are getting changed. I want the default font and want that animation. How to do it?

Thanks.  If you remove the portion labelled "Problematic Part" in the code then the "Hello" is printed differently than the case when you keep that
part.

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usetheme{AnnArbor} 
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Problematic Part
   \usepackage{times}
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% 





\usepackage{color} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{hyperref}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage[mathscr]{euscript}
      \theoremstyle{definition} 
\newtheorem*{dfn}{A Reasonable Definition} 

 \begin{document}

 \begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Hello}
          Hello
   \end{frame}

                \end{document}
```

Comment: Could you post a MWE?

Comment: @samcarter: did

Comment: There are some errors in your MWE. Comments are not on the same line/the comment flag is on new lines. After removing this probleme I get a `! Argument of \\beamercolorbox has an extra }.`-error. Can you check your MWE please?

Comment: @knut: sorry, it should work now.

Comment: I do not get any difference. The font, embedded at the end of the `pdflatex` run is `texmf-dist/fonts/type1/urw/helvetic/uhvr8a.pfb`. `pdffonts` shows `NimbusSanL-Regu(lar)`, also the Helvetica clon of URW.

Comment: Yes, the MWE is compiling, but I see no differences.A Binary compare shows only differences in timestamp and a PDF-Field /ID. Can you add a `\listfiles` in your example and post the versions you use?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP has found the cause of the problem, package `times`, and requests deletion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remark: This is no answer, but may help to find the problem. (an the content is too long for a comment)

I find no difference in the results.

If you add a `\listfiles` in the document header you get a list of all loaded packages at the end of the log-file.

Maybe you have a modified file or some personal configurations?

My list of files with the critical code gives:

```
 *File List*
  beamer.cls    2015/01/05 3.36 A class for typesetting presentations (rcs-revi
sion 8a39122e1f63)
beamerbasercs.sty    2015/03/08 (rcs-revision 368aa9ba9d38)
beamerbasemodes.sty    2013/09/03 (rcs-revision 768f2d98ca64)
beamerbasedecode.sty    2010/05/01 (rcs-revision efa082c6111d)
   ifpdf.sty    2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
beamerbaseoptions.sty    2013/03/10 (rcs-revision 47431932db0d)
  keyval.sty    2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
geometry.sty    2010/09/12 v5.6 Page Geometry
  ifvtex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.5 Detect VTeX and its facilities (HO)
 ifxetex.sty    2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
  size11.clo    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
 pgfcore.sty    2010/04/11 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.7)
graphicx.sty    2014/10/28 v1.0g Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
graphics.sty    2014/10/28 v1.0p Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2010/04/23 v1.9 graphics configuration of TeX Live
  pdftex.def    2011/05/27 v0.06d Graphics/color for pdfTeX
infwarerr.sty    2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
  pgfsys.sty    2013/11/30 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.47)
  pgfrcs.sty    2013/12/20 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.28)
everyshi.sty    2001/05/15 v3.00 EveryShipout Package (MS)
  pgfrcs.code.tex
  pgfsys.code.tex
pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex    2013/09/09  (rcs-revision 1.9)
pgfsysprotocol.code.tex    2006/10/16  (rcs-revision 1.4)
  xcolor.sty    2007/01/21 v2.11 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
dvipsnam.def    2014/10/14 v3.0j Driver-dependent file (DPC,SPQR)
 pgfcore.code.tex
 xxcolor.sty    2003/10/24 ver 0.1
atbegshi.sty    2011/10/05 v1.16 At begin shipout hook (HO)
hyperref.sty    2012/11/06 v6.83m Hypertext links for LaTeX
hobsub-hyperref.sty    2012/05/28 v1.13 Bundle oberdiek, subset hyperref (HO)
hobsub-generic.sty    2012/05/28 v1.13 Bundle oberdiek, subset generic (HO)
  hobsub.sty    2012/05/28 v1.13 Construct package bundles (HO)
ifluatex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
 intcalc.sty    2007/09/27 v1.1 Expandable calculations with integers (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2011/02/16 v1.5 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2012/04/25 v1.16 Key value parser (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2011/04/07 v1.3 Define keys (HO)
pdftexcmds.sty    2011/11/29 v0.20 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
pdfescape.sty    2011/11/25 v1.13 Implements pdfTeX's escape features (HO)
bigintcalc.sty    2012/04/08 v1.3 Expandable calculations on big integers (HO)
  bitset.sty    2011/01/30 v1.1 Handle bit-vector datatype (HO)
uniquecounter.sty    2011/01/30 v1.2 Provide unlimited unique counter (HO)
letltxmacro.sty    2010/09/02 v1.4 Let assignment for LaTeX macros (HO)
 hopatch.sty    2012/05/28 v1.2 Wrapper for package hooks (HO)
xcolor-patch.sty    2011/01/30 xcolor patch
atveryend.sty    2011/06/30 v1.8 Hooks at the very end of document (HO)
refcount.sty    2011/10/16 v3.4 Data extraction from label references (HO)
 hycolor.sty    2011/01/30 v1.7 Color options for hyperref/bookmark (HO)
 auxhook.sty    2011/03/04 v1.3 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
kvoptions.sty    2011/06/30 v3.11 Key value format for package options (HO)
  pd1enc.def    2012/11/06 v6.83m Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
hyperref.cfg    2002/06/06 v1.2 hyperref configuration of TeXLive
     url.sty    2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
 hpdftex.def    2012/11/06 v6.83m Hyperref driver for pdfTeX
rerunfilecheck.sty    2011/04/15 v1.7 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)
beamerbaserequires.sty    2010/05/01  (rcs-revision efa082c6111d)
beamerbasecompatibility.sty    2012/05/01  (rcs-revision 67c48b3b652d)
beamerbasefont.sty    2015/01/05  (rcs-revision b4b4bee242e2)
 amssymb.sty    2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS font symbols
amsfonts.sty    2013/01/14 v3.01 Basic AMSFonts support
sansmathaccent.sty    2013/03/28
filehook.sty    2011/10/12 v0.5d Hooks for input files
beamerbasetranslator.sty    2010/06/11  (rcs-revision 85fd1cc7fc42)
translator.sty    2010/06/12 ver 1.10
translator-language-mappings.tex
beamerbasemisc.sty    2013/09/03  (rcs-revision a55719c41d85)
beamerbasetwoscreens.sty    2010/05/01  (rcs-revision efa082c6111d)
beamerbaseoverlay.sty    2013/12/25  (rcs-revision f6bd5e3805da)
beamerbasetitle.sty    2010/09/21  (rcs-revision f0446ed0b6ae)
beamerbasesection.sty    2013/06/07  (rcs-revision 60b9fe0f342f)
beamerbaseframe.sty    2014/02/20  (rcs-revision 4b8ceeeff434)
beamerbaseverbatim.sty    2015/01/05  (rcs-revision 431510bb5890)
beamerbaseframesize.sty    2011/09/12  (rcs-revision 70f9d8411e54)
beamerbaseframecomponents.sty    2013/10/18  (rcs-revision 5cf6c5555a45)
beamerbasecolor.sty    2015/02/21  (rcs-revision d944b04ee2d5)
beamerbasenotes.sty    2012/12/19  (rcs-revision 1686da3db3c9)
beamerbasetoc.sty    2015/03/08  (rcs-revision 7270298bbaae)
beamerbasetemplates.sty    2010/05/01  (rcs-revision efa082c6111d)
beamerbaseauxtemplates.sty    2014/06/30  (rcs-revision 580088513a67)
beamerbaseboxes.sty    2012/05/13  (rcs-revision 56972908a390)
beamerbaselocalstructure.sty    2014/09/10  (rcs-revision 393f6dcff371)
enumerate.sty    2014/10/28 v3.00 enumerate extensions (DPC)
beamerbasenavigation.sty    2015/02/27  (rcs-revision 923f4bf87efa)
beamerbasetheorems.sty    2010/06/06  (rcs-revision 7e7cc5e53e9d)
 amsmath.sty    2013/01/14 v2.14 AMS math features
 amstext.sty    2000/06/29 v2.01
  amsgen.sty    1999/11/30 v2.0
  amsbsy.sty    1999/11/29 v1.2d
  amsopn.sty    1999/12/14 v2.01 operator names
  amsthm.sty    2009/07/02 v2.20.1
beamerbasethemes.sty    2010/05/01  (rcs-revision efa082c6111d)
beamerthemedefault.sty    2010/06/17  (rcs-revision d02a7cf4d8ae)
beamerfontthemedefault.sty    2012/12/19  (rcs-revision 1686da3db3c9)
beamercolorthemedefault.sty    2012/12/19  (rcs-revision 1686da3db3c9)
beamerinnerthemedefault.sty    2014/06/30  (rcs-revision 580088513a67)
beamerouterthemedefault.sty    2012/12/19  (rcs-revision 1686da3db3c9)
beamerthemeAnnArbor.sty    2010/06/17  (rcs-revision d02a7cf4d8ae)
beamerinnerthemerounded.sty    2010/06/17  (rcs-revision d02a7cf4d8ae)
beamerouterthemeinfolines.sty    2012/10/16  (rcs-revision 51a8c72084af)
beamercolorthemewolverine.sty    2010/06/17  (rcs-revision d02a7cf4d8ae)
inputenc.sty    2014/04/30 v1.2b Input encoding file
  latin1.def    2014/04/30 v1.2b Input encoding file
   times.sty    2005/04/12 PSNFSS-v9.2a (SPQR) 
    tikz.sty    2013/12/13 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.142)
     pgf.sty    2013/12/18 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.14)
pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty    2007/07/03 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.7)
pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty    2007/07/23 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.1)
  pgffor.sty    2013/12/13 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.25)
 pgfkeys.sty    
 pgfkeys.code.tex
 pgfmath.sty    
 pgfmath.code.tex
  pgffor.code.tex
    tikz.code.tex
verbatim.sty    2014/10/28 v1.5q LaTeX2e package for verbatim enhancements
 comment.sty    
euscript.sty    2009/06/22 v3.00 Euler Script fonts
  ot1phv.fd    2001/06/04 scalable font definitions for OT1/phv.
supp-pdf.mkii
epstopdf-base.sty    2010/02/09 v2.5 Base part for package epstopdf
  grfext.sty    2010/08/19 v1.1 Manage graphics extensions (HO)
epstopdf-sys.cfg    2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of (r)epstopdf for TeX Live
 nameref.sty    2012/10/27 v2.43 Cross-referencing by name of section
gettitlestring.sty    2010/12/03 v1.4 Cleanup title references (HO)
Namenlos-1.out
Namenlos-1.out
translator-basic-dictionary-English.dict    
translator-bibliography-dictionary-English.dict    
translator-environment-dictionary-English.dict    
translator-months-dictionary-English.dict    
translator-numbers-dictionary-English.dict    
translator-theorem-dictionary-English.dict    
 ***********
```

Can you compare it with your list?

Comment: sorry again. it was due to the package \usepackage{time}. problem solved. thanks for the help.